# Pandas - how to build and expanding window dataframe from a series

Tags: python, pandas, apply, rolling-computation

I'm not allowed to use any df.expanding().apply() solutions but need to go through an approach as the following.
Therefore, given a pd.Series such as

```
2008-12-31    1.4174
2009-01-01    1.4184
2009-01-02    1.4098
2009-01-05    1.4000
2009-01-06    1.3882
2009-01-07    1.4079
2009-01-08    1.4045
2009-01-09    1.4148
2009-01-12    1.4716
2009-01-13    1.4979
```

I would like to build a dataframe such as

```
2008-12-31  1.4174  1.4174  1.4174  1.4174  1.4174
2009-01-01  1.4184  1.4184  1.4184  1.4184  1.4184
2009-01-02  1.4098  1.4098  1.4098  1.4098  1.4098
2009-01-05  1.4000  1.4000  1.4000  1.4000  1.4000
2009-01-06  1.3882  1.3882  1.3882  1.3882  1.3882
2009-01-07  NaN     1.4079  1.4079  1.4079  1.4079
2009-01-08  NaN     NaN     1.4045  1.4045  1.4045
2009-01-09  NaN     NaN     NaN     1.4148  1.4148
2009-01-12  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     1.4716
2009-01-13  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

How can I proceed? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shift` and construct the data frame with `for` loop:

```
pd.DataFrame({
    i: s.shift(i).shift(-i) for i in range(1,6)
})
```

Output:

```
                 1       2       3       4       5
Date                                              
2008-12-31  1.4174  1.4174  1.4174  1.4174  1.4174
2009-01-01  1.4184  1.4184  1.4184  1.4184  1.4184
2009-01-02  1.4098  1.4098  1.4098  1.4098  1.4098
2009-01-05  1.4000  1.4000  1.4000  1.4000  1.4000
2009-01-06  1.3882  1.3882  1.3882  1.3882  1.3882
2009-01-07  1.4079  1.4079  1.4079  1.4079     NaN
2009-01-08  1.4045  1.4045  1.4045     NaN     NaN
2009-01-09  1.4148  1.4148     NaN     NaN     NaN
2009-01-12  1.4716     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2009-01-13     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```